# In App Billing purchases not on Google Play / Weird Receipts

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

We've noticed that are a lot of in app billing payment records on our server that aren't reflected on Google Play Order Management. After looking at the receipts, we've noticed several differences between the ones from Order Management vs the ones that aren't there. For those that aren't on Order Management:

- (Always) Order ID is apparently using the older format: 3925053605191231569.4699441885150531
- (Always) purchaseToken is quite short: neliazyrqesvgwagglfwccfa
- (Usually) title is almost the IAB item id, without an underscore: "standardannual subscription"
- (Usually) description is almost the IAB item id, without an underscore: "standardannual_subscription"
- (Usually) price is wrong and without the denomination (such as "0.11" or "0.26", rather than "$59.99")

Below is a passing and a failing order receipt.

After reading, my impression is that it's possibly fraudulent charges, but don't have an intuition as to the likelihood. If it isn't fraudulent charges, we do have a lot of incentive to figure it out as we would be leaving money on the table. Google Play's help team has confirmed it wouldn't be an invalid credit card or spotty internet connection. Any thoughts on what would be going on would be awesome.

**failing receipt**

> {"id":"standardannual_subscription","alias":"BodBot Plus -
>   Annual","type":"paid
>   subscription","state":"owned","title":"standardannual
>   subscription","description":"standardannual
>   subscription","priceMicros":26000000,"price":"0.26","currency":"USD","loaded":true,"canPurchase":false,"owned":true,"downloading":false,"downloaded":false,"additionalData":null,"transaction":{"type":"android-playstore","id":"3925053605191231569.4699441885150531","purchaseToken":"neliazyrqesvgwagglfwccfa","developerPayload":"","receipt":"{\"orderId\":\"3925053605191231569.4699441885150531\",\"packageName\":\"com.bodbot.trainer\",\"productId\":\"standardannual_subscription\",\"purchaseTime\":1500112205250,\"purchaseState\":0,\"developerPayload\":\"\",\"purchaseToken\":\"neliazyrqesvgwagglfwccfa\"}","signature":"A4uP+JUzu7UJfD56y9g1Btym7gHRUvnwb7dgxR9lswR9D3a21JkCKU0YWkDKBiFVSyfiwW3CLWTuamwNsXVKU5UXjI+krbvcMDjEUlrmhZP4LApGVpJQG4eSWqib7LkBBBZPXAMBuX5HL7hHk1XSwh/oKxnm0NqQIlD6kd4sVGypDvMdRUofHu5AfkcEYRC0YIg46AoipXurbaCXMbv3lQYXjs+TGl7GxFRIuiseCr9BReAgxV0lQ5XZylB/QIatwWYDdGfkGNMtu0Bc/lUet6f2TW+sflGpVDMHNWdcSQkl+A/DEVK67M8B/eVl/w8="},"valid":true}

**passing receipt**

> {"id":"standardannual_subscription","alias":"BodBot Plus -
>   Annual","type":"paid subscription","state":"owned","title":"BodBot
>   Plus - Annual (BodBot Personal
>   Trainer:\u00a0Workout\u00a0&\u00a0Fitness\u00a0Coach)","description":"BodBot
>   Plus enhances BodBot's personalization through a suite of powerful
>   \ntools.","priceMicros":59990000,"price":"$59.99","currency":"USD","loaded":true,"canPurchase":false,"owned":true,"downloading":false,"downloaded":false,"additionalData":null,"transaction":{"type":"android-playstore","id":"GPA.3389-7532-0097-99951","purchaseToken":"bhjlmpicpacconeppfjalipi.AO-J1OziYOBRhZsG12KwcvuyRpOc7zhRCDsyW8C-YfRphW3UeVTbHFbt5tKoQC0vaCGE-lMq-64Qu3zwkX2KRA9yjo1u0Wr93vlGBX2QKZMHR37B8rVsI2IZXWjpeTtR5qo29u79X7li","developerPayload":null,"receipt":"{\"orderId\":\"GPA.3389-7532-0097-99951\",\"packageName\":\"com.bodbot.trainer\",\"productId\":\"standardannual_subscription\",\"purchaseTime\":1499974851578,\"purchaseState\":0,\"purchaseToken\":\"bhjlmpicpacconeppfjalipi.AO-J1OziYOBRhZsG12KwcvuyRpOc7zhRCDsyW8C-YfRphW3UeVTbHFbt5tKoQC0vaCGE-lMq-64Qu3zwkX2KRA9yjo1u0Wr93vlGBX2QKZMHR37B8rVsI2IZXWjpeTtR5qo29u79X7li\",\"autoRenewing\":true}","signature":"PT1vE2lTe8geQ2JYi3YISSYxVNuQAWO3a4uzjMp+UEr3l/p95hVs4j1TAHKvnpyqB/+dQUSddLGjqcVPLTgXDBvET7owy3dqA3G//hrsw2ORewHyD3iPI/56lr8onTOry8nPZXL+z2ziBhCmiUNue3RhVteepVdnUMaGz8ws24VYgKP9u4g8fc7hBcrzI3rTcufrn4MCauB+XhVLHa0y/AREPnvYg4MjgrEwVjf8HhPU+7w8hMKfpt9XC6VVdwYAPH54pYJO+YEsnYNkHIPJNbGuq2eiW/GbCxwuKtuP9bmaB7RQFA/HCWLqQNkt7lkL+ch4my2+1QZEsIVDz9s0qQ=="},"valid":true}

Comment: We have the same problem. Do you have any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is most obviously a fraudulent transaction obtained through a flow similar to described in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402531/google-iap-returns-short-purchase-token-for-verification/35388483#35388483).

To confirm the suspicion, try offline validation of the signature of a failing receipt (use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45902319/8513835) as a guidance for Java or Ruby) and most likely it will not pass it (as in your provided example signature is 239 bytes long after decoding, instead of expected 256) thus indicating this is a fraud one

Just to summarize wider fraudulent symptoms:

- Order Management console fails to find such order
- Old-style order id present in format `[merchant ID].[actual order ID]`
- PurchaseToken seems to have short/random/unexpected length
- Order signature validation failures

Please post your findings if you're discovered something otherwise